# open master page without navigation bar xamarin forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, master-detail, navigationbar

Simple one now (I guess)...

(...) (old text sucked)

The image below states the list page navigation bar as is now.

[image]

this is the objective (of course, colorful and all that):

[image]

(as stated before, no custom renderers and no native code is allowed; the idea is the company is to show that xamarin can do all the native can, and even more, without being native - I'll leave judgement for the reader)

thank you very much.

Comment: Your edited question, although confusing, doesn't look like it's really all that related to your initial question. Imo, you should treat your original question separately (and I did fully answer it). And start a new question for your new issue. Please try to write out the new question more clearly, as currently I'm not entirely sure what exactly is it that you are asking in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a pretty good solution here:

- http://blog.twintechs.com/advanced-xamarin-forms-techniques-for-flexible-and-performant-cross-platform-apps-part-5-page-in-page-embedding

even if it is not approved by xamarin, the idea on its own is awsome, and worked perfectly for what I needed. also (and this is a frequent thing actually) manager changed his mind, and allowed me to proceed with an idea I had (and was even before knowing that Google had actually approve it as followable guidelines), which consisted of creating a custom contentview that would serve as bottom navigation bar, cross-platform, using tap gestures, and each item of this "tab" will change the main application page.

still, thank you very much for all your answers, all of them helped a lot, is just that I am not allowed many changes to the xamarin main controls, would not know how to perform most of them even if allowed, and came from a native Android background, in which neither architectures, nor how you make it (as long as it works well) are the followed principles, so I am still unable (and not really willing to, given the kind of projects I am working with) to follow microsoft specific architectures and guidelines...

Answer (score 2):

I have done that long time ago (around a year) and I do not have the code snippet unfortunately. 
So I can share my experience.

To hide the navigation bar you can use

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```

I think this one can be used inside the detail pages (as you know nowadays you put the detail page inside a navigation page)  so maybe you can set the navigation bar to false  (if Xamarin.Forms still supports it)

This [link](https://www.syntaxismyui.com/xamarin-forms-masterdetail-page-navigation-recipe/) shows how to master MasterDetailPage , although it is quite old,but it might still be helpful.

Another great resource and more up-to-date is the official book for xamarin.forms [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/).

When in my company we made a master detailed page , there were two ways to call the master page

1. By swiping from left to right
2. Using the burger button

I don't claim having the right answer , but maybe what i shared can be helpful.

Comment: thanks so much for you answer. in this case, I've already hidden the navigation bar, and I can't allow gestures on the master page, because I'm also using a carousel page inside this navigation page, so it could get confused (as Xamarin also alerts). The burger button allows to open the master page, of course, but only if shown in the navigation bar; else no go, and there lies my problem...

Comment: I read that if you put in the Master Detail Page (or maybe the master page) the icon to burger image. then this would solve the problem . Dont know where did I see that though

Comment: oh yes, you're right BraveHeart, I'm not saying you're not, and it works perfectly, I have it working so far, but I can't access the icon outside the navigation bar, and shouldn't be using a navigation bar here... just updated the question

Comment: and BraveHeart, I apologize, but under no circumstances I'm allowed to share code (another company policy - you know, they're kind of against open source, and pro microsoft in all ways possible - fortunatelly I'm not here for much longer...)

Comment: IF this problem not allowing you to move forward , you can always make a small solution with code that has this issue

Comment: it's ok, i'm still doing a lot of work on the app, just was trying to solve this issue before it becomes the only thing left to do. still, i already managed (due to their fanatism for xamarin and apple), to convince them to allow a small change in the layout, in which case i'll have a tabbed page serving as the menu, and inside each tab i'll display the appropriate pages. though this isn't the best approach for android, it seems to serve ios and winphone very well, so they're happy, i keep not caring, and we all move on. i just wouldn't like this to remain unfinished business. thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Manually displaying or hiding the Master page in the MasterDetail pattern is quite easy in Xamarin.Forms.

There is a property of MasterDetailPage called "IsPresented" which you can read, and you can set it to True to show the master page and False to hide it. It will be animated just as it is when you press the hamburger icon.

There is also an event called IsPresentedChanged which is useful for those who *are* using the toolbar and or gestures to allow the master page to open, so they can get notified when it happens.

Comment: thank you very much, makes perfect sense, although now I must come up with another question. How can I access both the property and the event outside the MasterDetailPage? that is my current issue. I already tried even with a property in App.cs, but can't seem to grasp it. Just updated the question

Comment: I'm sorry, but I find your edited question highly confusing. It seems that you are using some convoluted custom way of storing page references and performing navigation. You also seem overly critical of Xamarin.Forms although it is clear you do not understand the best practices of using it. If you can upload your project or reword your question so I actually understand what it is that you are asking, I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: edited. I apologize for sounding confusing, it seems to be usual. anyway, my issue is not xamarin itself. I find it instructive and to be a good solution when you're experimenting or just programming kids games, or something, that doesn't require a professional native UX; but that's exactly what this app requires, and my issue is having to operate miracles when not even the xamarin team gives a damn, as they were the ones stating multiple times that there are things they can't simply make native, because they work completely differently between platforms (but the adm seems unable to get it)...